# Unicode characters writen as questions marks by LuaTeX

Tags: unicode, lua, latex, octave

This Lua script defined in a tex file:

```
\begin{luacode*}

function run_octave_script(octavescript)

  local command = os.getenv("HOME") " " .. octavescript

  local outputfile = io.popen(command)
  local outputtext = outputfile:read("*all")
  outputfile:close()

  for line in outputtext:gmatch("[^\n]+") do  
    tex.print(line)
    tex.print("")
  end

end

\end{luacode*}
```

captures the text output of an Octave script and copies it in a text box:

```
\newenvironment{scriptbox}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \fontsize{16pt}{22pt}
    \fontspec{DejaVu Sans Mono}
    }{ 
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\runscript}[1]{\directlua{run_octave_script("#1")}}
```

when called like this:

```
\begin{scriptbox}
\runscript{myscript(1,2);}
\end{scriptbox}
```

The output might contain Unicode symbols, like the "Em Quad" character (U+2001) or "element of" (U+2208), and the Lua script writes them as "???", even if the Octave script outputs the original Unicode characters (both in the Octave prompt, and from the terminal), while others Unicode symbols are rendered correctly (e.g. the union of sets).

This is an example of the output to the TeX file:

```
{(a,a), (c,a), (c,c)}???∪???{(a,c), (b,c), (c,a)}
```

where two Em Quad symbols have been replaced by question marks.

The DejaVu Sans Mono font is available for the Lua 5.4.4 compiler:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --find="DejaVu Sans Mono"
luaotfload | resolve : Font "DejaVu Sans Mono" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf"
```

and contains these symbols. The system is also using UTF-8:

```
$ locale charmap | grep -qi 'utf-\+8' && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."
Uses UTF-8 encoding..
```

The code used to work fine on an Ubuntu 18.04, but when upgraded to 22.04 it generates this problem. Can't figure out what was making it work in the former (and older) distro version.

Comment: What exactly is the `command` in `io.popen()` ?

Comment: @ESkri it runs an Octave script which outputs the result as lines of text. When run from the a shell or the Octave prompt this text can be read properly, including the Unicode characters; when run from the Lua script these characters display as '???'. Actually, it is the same for several Octave scripts, not just one.

Comment: Try `io.popen("LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 "..command)`

Comment: @ESkri that did the trick, solved!